# Multivariable version of Spivak calculus book

Tags: calculus

Is there a multivariable version of Spivak calculus book?

Comment: Perhaps Spivaks books on differential geometry? The first two of the five volumes give a very readable theoretical and historical background.

Comment: His little book on manifolds is as close as you can get.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe [***Spivak - Calculus on Manifolds***](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0805390219) is what you're searching for, it covers:

1. Functions on Euclidean Space

   - Norm and Inner Product
   - Subsets of Euclidean Space
   - Functions and Continuity
2. Differentiation

   - Basic Definitions
   - Basic Theorems
   - Partial Derivatives
   - Derivatives
   - Inverse Functions
   - Implicit Functions
   - Notation
3. Integration

   - Basic Definitions
   - Measure Zero and Content Zero
   - Integrable Functions
   - Fubini's Theorem
   - Partitions of Unity
   - Change of Variable
4. Integration on Chains

   - Algebraic Preliminaries
   - Fields and Forms
   - Geometric Preliminaries
   - The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus
5. Integration on Manifolds

   - Manifolds
   - Fields and Forms on Manifolds
   - Stokes' Theorem on Manifolds
   - The Volume Element
   - The Classical Theorems